# Mod_Rewrite for Apache2 doesn't work for machine requests like curl. What can I do to forward those requests?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https, apache2, passenger

I just set up SSL on my server. I wanted old requests to the http site to forward to https. The works great in the browser with a rewrite condition and a rewrite rule in Apache2. However, one of our partners has a server that makes requests to a certain URL, and the site doesn't seem to be rewriting those URL's properly.

I try to recreate this behavior using curl. When I make the url request with https (i.e. curl https://......), it works properly and finishes the request as expected. When I make the request the url request with http (i.e. curl http://.......), it returns html text that says this page has bee redirected to https://..... . When I do either the http or the https request in the browser, it rewrites properly.

Update: I should say here that this is merely a diagnostic for the observed behavior. As per the comment below, you can set curl to follow redirects, but I don't think the machine that is making requests (of which I am trying to accommodate) to the server is able to follow redirects in this manner.

Further update: If anyone knows where it would be logged that the "redirect notification" was sent (in apache logs), please let me know. Then I would be able to tell what requests weren't redirected and be able to tell if the "curl diagnostic" above is illegitimate. Thanks!

Any advice appreciated and thank you for all your help. Please let me know if you need any clarification or if there is any Apache configuration or further diagnostics I should provide.

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell cURL to follow (HTTP) redirections (this is disabled by default). You can do this by passing it the `-L` option if you're invoking cURL via command-line. If you're invoking it from PHP for example, you set the header `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` via the [`curl_setopt`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) function.

Comment: I revised the question. That is helpful to know, but I don't think the machine making requests to the site is following redirects.